# Why are requests taking so long when using docker on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, containers

On my Windows 10 laptop I run the same application as two other people. One of them is Windows desktop user, the other one is a MAC user. Comparing to them, my requests are taking a lot longer (4-8 times as long). Especially the APP time is high(see screenshot below). Docker uses wsl2. The application is a simple Laravel application which contains some simple endpoints.

[image: Request performance]

I am using a laptop which I think is not the problem and has

- 32 gb ram
- intel core vPRO i7
- NVMe KIOXIA 512

What can be the problem?

Comment: There are performance implications on various host OSes if you're trying to use a bind mount instead of packaging your application code in a Docker image.  But without seeing a [mcve] it's almost impossible to do more than guess.  Can you edit the question to include enough details to demonstrate the situation?

Comment: Are you comparing with other user running same dockerized service?

Comment: I am having the same situation, seems to be a problem with networking between containers and host machine. In my case I see it when going to MySQL where I even see connections being not established successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the actual application which you are containerizing it is tricky to come up with a solution, however, with a environment similar to yours I came with a similar situation, on which the performance bottleneck came from the volume mounts which I created.

This cross OS volume mount between Windows and Unix filesystems is a common bottleneck, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/10476)